# Is there any easy way to determine two Table Objects Equivalent in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

I used a method like this :

```
def compareTables(tb1,tb2){
    if(tb1.rows() != tb2.rows()) return false
    if(tb1.cols() != tb2.cols()) return false
    for(colname in tb1.columnNames()){
        for(row in 0:tb1.rows()){
            if(tb1[colname][row] != tb2[colname][row]) return false
        }
    }    
    return true
}
```

Buuuuuut..... I really don't like it.  it's so inefficient and cumbersome.
Is there a more elegant and efficient way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

each(eqObj, tb1.values(), tb2.values(), 6).all()